# Show numeric keyboard without other symbols in Android

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

Is there a way to show keyboard without symbols like *, #?

I would like to display keyboard only with decimal keys.

I've read http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType and currently I'm using:

```
android:inputType="textPassword|number"
```

... but it doesn't work like I want.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Create a custom keyboard...buddy!!

Comment: Use "numberPassword" instead of "textPassword"